# Getting this error when running python 3 version on macOS sierra 10.12

Tags: python

Please any one help me, I am reading a fasta file through python3.6 or 3.5 on my macOS sierra and getting this error but code working properly when running on windows machine with python 3.5.2.
Please any one tell me what's the actual problem.
I install twice python on my mac but nothing works.

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 647: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python UnicodeDecodeError on Mac, but not on PC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33114999/python-unicodedecodeerror-on-mac-but-not-on-pc)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the python of the system. I am myself on macOS and I went crazy several times with Apple tricks. I strongly advise to install python with anaconda, it is very simple and then you can try as many environments you want with different versions of python and of the modules. And you have a much better control.

Sorry if this is not a fully documented answer, it is more like a comment but I do not have permission to give comments anymore (reputation loss due to a bounty). I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, Stephane. I use pycharm editor but I also heard Anaconda is nice. But the problem is still with Anaconda. I searched on google and it says that because mac use unicode utf-8 and PC use different thing like Ascii. Thanks for your suggestion.